# Tagging questions related to Linear Referencing, Dynamic Segmentation and Chainage?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We currently have the following tags (and their wiki entries) related to Linear Referencing, Dynamic Segmentation and Chainage, and there may be more (feel free to edit and add).

Often several of them occur on the same question, suggesting that there may be some confusion/overlap in the "definitions" applied here in their wikis and wiki excerpts.

- [linear-referencing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-referencing) - 96 questions

> Linear referencing is the method of storing geographic locations by
>   using relative positions along a measured linear feature.

- [lrs](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lrs) - 2 questions

> No wiki but presumably stands for Linear Referencing System

- [dynamic-segmentation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-segmentation) - 8 questions

> No wiki but 5 out of 8 questions are also tagged [linear-referencing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-referencing)

- [qchainage](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qchainage) - 5 questions

> No wiki but [Wiktionary for chainage](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chainage) talks about distance along a line

Should some or all of these be made synonyms?

Comment: I merged [tag:lrs] into [tag:linear-referencing] to resolve this Q&A.  No actions were taken on the other proposals mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose that [lrs](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lrs) be made synonym of [linear-referencing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-referencing). I agree they appear to mean the same thing, and shorthand/acronyms are often cryptic if not near universally known - particularly in tagging systems.

I would leave the others and update Wikis as needed. Underdark's answer has already addressed qchainage. Dynamic Segmentation is related to but a sub-topic of linear referencing, at least in the ArcGIS tool/help structure. This would relate to the granularity issue, but per my comment on Underdark's answer granularity isn't a bad thing unless taken to extreme excess. Granted, where that line falls is going to be a subjective matter. But I think better to have the split from the start than have to deal with creating it down the line when there's a thousand questions and 40% are about the grain and not the beach.

Answer (score 3):

QChainage is a specific QGIS plugin https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qchainage/. I wouldn't recommend making a specific tool a synonym of a broader concept such as lrs.

Comment: ... but with only 5 questions tagged [tag:QChainage] (plus [three more untagged that mention it](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=qchainage+is%3Aquestion)) in over 4.5 years does it really warrant a separate tag?

Comment: Why not? Topics like [tag:matlab-mapping-toolbox] have a tag too. Just because it's really focused doesn't make it bad imho.

Comment: Not bad, but I think overly granular - my preference would be to put [tag:matlab-mapping-toolbox] as a synonym of [tag:matlab] (only 51 questions) too.

Comment: I stand by my point that mixing concepts and tool tags seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: It is mixing concept and tool tags but for the sake of pragmatism I think that is OK for tags that are rarely used.

Comment: @PolyGeo Rarely now... but all tags, unless retroactively created and applied, have to start somewhere/with a small number of applications. Past results do not guarantee future performance, as they so often say with investing. What may be granular now could be broader in the future, and I see no reason to intentionally make it harder to find that grain in a bigger sandbox or beach. I'd just fix the Wiki.

Comment: OK - I can go along with this now - I just re-checked the QChainage questions and I thought I had seen them spanning four or so years but it looks like they are all since November last year which puts it into the "few hundred questions in next few years" range that makes it tag worthy to me rather than being well outside of it.